# Unlocking only specific ZFS datasets at boot

Tags: zfs, nixos

I have the following datasets in a ZFS pool:

```
NAME                    USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                  3.68G   185G   192K  none
rpool/FOO              3.43M   185G   192K  none
rpool/FOO/ds           3.24M   185G  3.05M  /home/ds
rpool/FOO/ds/sdk        192K   185G   192K  /home/ds/sdk
rpool/ROOT             3.68G   185G  3.68G  legacy
```

I would like to mount `rpool/ROOT` as `/` on boot, so I need to load its encryption key from a user prompt. I don't want to mount `rpool/FOO/*` on boot, and I don't want a user prompt for its encryption key on boot -- I will load its key and mount it later with some other process.

This looks like a job for [`boot.zfs.requestEncryptionCredentials`](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=23.11&show=boot.zfs.requestEncryptionCredentials&from=0&size=30&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=boot.zfs.requestEncryptionCredentials) but I can't figure out how to use it:

- If I set it to the (singleton) list `["rpool/ROOT"]`, then I get no password  prompt at boot, and thus subsequently `NixOS Stage 1` fails with `Key load error: Keys must be loaded for encryption root of 'rpool/ROOT' (rpool)`.
- If I set it to `true`, then I get two password prompts: one for `rpool/ROOT` and one for `rpool/FOO/ds`. This is exactly what I want to avoid.

The example in the option documentation is a bit weird because it doesn't look like the usual `<pool>/<dataset>` syntax of ZFS:

> **Example**:
>
> ```
> [   
>   "tank"   
>   "data" 
> ]
> ```

so I'm not sure if my using `"rpool/FOO"` is the correct syntax.